# How does the human eye generate spikes?

Tags: vision, theoretical-biology

**Disclaimer**: I have an academic background in computer vision but not biological vision.

**Background**: Classical computer vision is concerned with images from cameras that have a fixed exposure time for all pixels. During this exposure time, each pixel is essentially counting photons. This photon count then translates to a bitmap (usually 8 bits per pixel for monochrome cameras) which can be displayed on monitors.

However, the human/vertebrates brain does (afaik) not operate on integers or floating point values but spikes. Consequently, the brain must convert light to spikes for further processing.

**Biologically inspired machine vision**:
Let me quickly present you the simplified working principle of two major approaches of biologically inspired machine vision. They are the inspiration for this question.

1. [*Event Camera*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_camera): The event camera has independent pixels that respond to changes in their logarithmic intensity $L = \log(I)$ ("brightness"). An event/spike is triggered at a certain pixel as soon as the brightness increment since the last event at the pixel reaches a threshold.
   Formally, let $e_k = (\mathbf{x}_k, t_k, p_k)$ be the event at pixel $\mathbf{x}_k=(x_k, y_k)$ at time $t_k$ with polarity $p_k\in\{+1, -1\}$ as the sign of the brightness change. Then an event $e_k$ is triggered if
   $$
   L(\mathbf{x}_k, t_k) - L(\mathbf{x}_k, t_k - \Delta t_k) = p_k C
   $$,
   where $C>0$ and $\Delta t_k$ is the time elapsed since the last event at the same pixel. C is the contrast sensitivity and determines how much the brightness has to change to trigger an event/spike. This introduction is adapted from section 2.4 of [this survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.08405.pdf). For a more visual explanation see [this introductory video](https://youtu.be/SU_Fp4xS_g4).

*Consequence of this working priciple*: This camera only generates output when there is motion in the scene. Furthermore, it is not possible to reconstruct the actual intensity given spikes/events of an event camera. This is because the camera only generates output at intensity differences (it is a differential sensor).

2. *Spike Camera*: This camera also has independent pixel much like the event camera. However, each pixel integrates luminance intensity over time and emits a spike whenever a threshold is reached. This means that it essentially emits spikes to a rate proportional to the light intensity. More formally, let $I(t)$ be the intensity of a pixel at time $t$. Then a spike is generated at that pixel when
   $$
   \int_0^tI(\tau)\text{d}\tau\geq \phi
   $$,
   where $\phi$ is a threshold. More details are given in section 2.1 of [this paper](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2020/html/Zhu_Retina-Like_Visual_Image_Reconstruction_via_Spiking_Neural_Model_CVPR_2020_paper.html). Also have a look at the supplementary video for a visual impression.

*Consequence of this working principle*: Intensity is conveyed via rates of spikes. This rate is proportional to the measured photocurrent. Thus it is possible to reconstruct the true intensity at a pixel. Unlike the event camera, this camera also generates spikes when the scene is static.

**My question**: Can the spike generation mechanism of vertebrates vision be explained with these working principles? If not, is there another spike generation model that can be formulated mathematically?

**Why I am asking this question**: Literature regarding both cameras argue with biological inspiration but I have not found any evidence that either one of those approaches actually mimic the working principle of vertebrates' eyes. Any pointer to publications are welcome.

Comment: Are you acquainted with Carver Mead's work on bio-inspired, "neuromorphic systems" such as CCD sensors and the like?

Comment: I am aware of his pioneering works in neuromorphic systems but have not read his publications in depth because it is out of my field a bit.